# How to create a Drupal database on the server if you only have access via an FTP client

Tags: database

I am a bit confused about how to set up server database,because my host provider(is a university site),only provided me with a ftp client username and password. I don't have access to phpmyadmin.:/

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask your server admin to create a database and a user for that database to be able to install drupal. You don't need phpmyadmin but you do need a database/user.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get a username and password generated by administrator as well and maybe the computer name where the database is installed it is usually on a localhost but that depends on the way the network is setup